# How to make FileStream files available to a web app

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, filestream, file-storage

I've been trying to figure out the best way of making files stored in a Sql Server db as a `FILESTREAM` available to a web application.

Basically, I have a Web App written with Vue, an ASP.NET CORE WebApi backing it and when the user uploads an image (which is stored in the DB as a `varbinary(max) FILESTREAM`) the user should be able to view the image in browser.

I want to use an `<img src="{url to image}"/>`

So the question is: How do I get the `{url to image}` for the `img` tag from the record in the db. And I need it to 1. Work across multiple servers, so if the web app and db are on different servers. and 2. i need to url to be an alias so as not to give away the folder structure where the files are stored.

I'm also open to any suggestions on how to handle file storage differently if necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a small image (under 5KiB) you could get-away with Base64-encoding the raw data into an inline `data:` URI for the image.

Otherwise, you'll need to write a new Controller Action that only serves up image data. Remember to set the correct content-type too. Pass in the record key as a URI parameter.

```
[Route("/record-images/{recordPrimaryKey}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage( Int32 recordPrimaryKey )
{
    using( SqlConnection c = ... )
    using( SqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand() )
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ..."; // I assume the raw file data is returned through `SqlDataReader`. I assume that FILESTREAM is just a back-end storage concern.
        using( SqlDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync() )
        {
            if( !rdr.Read() ) return this.NotFound();

            Byte[] imageData = rdr.GetBytes( 0 );
            String contentType = rdr.GetString( 1 );
            return this.File( imageData, contentType );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I haven't tried this, but yeah I think this will work and is probably the simplest answer. But before I mark this as the correct answer, are there any alternatives to this that you can think of? I'm mostly asking because this is such a common thing in the web world (to serve an image from a DB) that I was hoping there would be a 'tried and tested, pre-written' solution that wouldn't have to require me writing custom code like this.

Comment: @LukeBourne In trivial web-applications you typically store the URI of the image file in the database and the image file is stored in a CDN or blob-storage account (S3, Azure Blobs, etc) or the web-server's own file-system and served as a static file. In general it is not recommended to store large blobs in relational databases - though I know things are different with `FILESTREAM`. I would still personally not do what you're doing.

Comment: I like the idea of using a FILESTREAM because I really want to tightly couple the record in the DB with the file on the actual system. Whereas if it's loosely coupled in the way you described (where you just store the URI) it means there are 2 points of maintenance and the DB can never guarantee the state of the physical file.
What would you personally do?

Comment: @LukeBourne I personally use blob storage for economic and practical reasons. In my experience the concerns about the risk of files going missing or being kept out-of-sync are overblown, especially if you practice good information-security and make backups. The main reason for storing blobs outside of the database is economic: blob storage is *very cheap* per gigabyte whereas relational storage is considerably more expensive. There's also no guarantee another RDBMS product will have a similar feature. The only time I store blobs in an RDBMS is if it's less than a few kilobytes.

Comment: Okay thanks very much, I'll mark this as the correct answer but I'll take on board what you've said and do a bit more research, thanks!